# How to recover COM objects which have not been properly released?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, com-interop, taskmanager

When someone uses the Task Manager to end a .NET process which has instantiated a COM object, AFAIK there is no way to call `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` in a `try {} finally {}`, `using {}` or event handling block.

The next time I fire up the application, the COM object is in an unusable state and I need to reboot the machine to make it work again.

I use `Marshal.BindToMoniker` to instantiate the object.

What am I doing wrong, is there anything I missed?

---

I tried Saeed's suggestion but it didn't work

```
private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE)
    {
        logger.Info("WM_CLOSE");
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObject);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: I think you could hook task manager end process message, then you can use marshal.release to prevent from bad releases, but for hooking messages, there are some articles in vc++ I don't know if there is for c# or not (anyway you could wrap it with com to use it in c#).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, see my answer below

Comment: I don't think WM_CLOSE is a suitable message for this, may be if you try some other messages you could get a result(it's a long time i'm not working on related stuff, and my long term memory is weak;). But by wont work, you mean if you run it in debug mode you couldn't step into your program?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I mean the log line wasn't fired and didn't write to the file

Comment: Yes, I didn't see your log. May be this way is wrong, but you could search more WM_*, may be is better to check it with spy++.

Comment: What kind of COM objects are these? Singleton or instance? In-proc or out-of-proc? In-proc objects will be destroyed with your process. Out-of-proc objects will be cleaned up after around 6 minutes. But if the object is instance, then the old object shouldn't matter.

Comment: "When someone uses the Task Manager to end a .NET process" - you do realize that this isn't a normal shutdown process, and so you shouldn't be surprised if it produces abnormal behaviour afterwards?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Spy++ logged only normal events (GetIcon, etc) before the process terminated, I get no Destroy nor Close message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task Manager is using the native equivalent of [`Process.Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) (or possibly something even stronger). Note this narrative from the documentation:

> **`Kill`** forces a termination of the process, while [`CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) only requests a termination.
>
> ...
>
> Calling `CloseMainWindow` sends a request to close to the main window, which, in a well-formed application...

And,

> Data edited by the process or resources allocated to the process can be lost if you call **`Kill`**. **`Kill`** causes an abnormal process termination and should be used only when necessary.

In short, there's nothing you can really do from inside your program code to protect against this - the plug has been pulled. No window messages are going to be sent.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Task Manager calls [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714.aspx) to kill tasks when the user clicks End Process on the Processes tab and cleanly with WM_CLOSE messages when End Task is clicked on the Applications tab. Also, [Raymond Chen's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx) explains why you can't stop TerminateProcess.

Comment: So my solution, if it exists, must be in the way I recover my object from such a crash, not in how I handle the abrut termination.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to.  When the garbage collector gets around to freeing the memory, it checks to see if the objects have a Dispose() method that hasn't been called yet.  If the Dispose() method hasn't been called, it will call it.

I was testing this in a console app and had 3 speaker beeps in my Dispose function.  After exiting the application, without calling Dispose on the object, it took about 30 seconds for the 3 beeps to be heard.  The time is in-determinant.

Of course, the object has to have been coded correctly.

Are you trying to run the application immediately after shutdown?  Why not wait a few minutes and see if it works?

EDIT:  I am assuming you have Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject in your Dispose function.

Comment: It didn't happen, no log was written to a file when the logger was called from an IDisposable.Dispose method.